# how to pass the filename of the valum upload plugin to a post method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload

I got this code for my valum upload plugin [this plugin](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/), I want to get the filename to use it in a $.post method, but I dont know how, any advises?, I need the filename outside of the qq.FileUploader plugin

```
 var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
                    element: document.getElementById('demo'),
                    listElement: document.getElementById('separate-list'),
                    action: '../../correo/controller/controllerSubirArchivos.php',
                   // name: 'qqfile',
                    debug:false,

                    allowedExtensions:['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif', ],
                    sizeLimit: 10000000, //10MB maximo
                    onSubmit: function(id, fileName){

                        //alert (fileName);

                    }

                });
```

I am searching but I dont find how? any help very appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really sure I understand what you mean. You can store the filename in a global variable for example and use it when you need it:

```
var UploadedFileNames = [];

var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
    element: document.getElementById('demo'),
    listElement: document.getElementById('separate-list'),
    action: '../../correo/controller/controllerSubirArchivos.php',
    // name: 'qqfile',
    debug:false,
    allowedExtensions:['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif', ],
    sizeLimit: 10000000, //10MB maximo
    onSubmit: function(id, fileName){
        UploadedFileNames.push(fileName);
    }
});

// later ...
$.post({ }); // you can use UploadedFileNames here
// if you want to have all the filenames concatenated, you can do:
alert(UploadedFileNames.join(' '));
```

Comment: thanks for answering do you know how to concatenate two filenames?, I mean your solution works perfect but If I got two files and so on??

Comment: @GeorgeBecj - I've updated my example to store filenames into an array; you can concatenate them later with `.join`.

Comment: @draevor do you know how to SET a custom name to the file to be saved?

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet If by "custom name" you mean to save the files with a different name, just do it in PHP where you receive them. Otherwise I don't really understand what you mean.

Comment: Yes i tried that, but the javascript response returns the original filename, so i can't track the name..